# @IBDesignable , NSLayoutConstraint for proportional multiplier width of superview?

Tags: ios, swift3, nslayoutconstraint

In an `@IBDesignable`,

I'm trying to programmatically set "width 20% of parent":

```
@IBDesignable
class TwentyPercentExample:UIView {

    func setup() {
        let cWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: self,
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width,
            relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,
            toItem: self.superview,
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width,
            multiplier: 0.2,
            constant:0
        )
        addConstraint(cWidth)
        print("I seemed to added the width constraint....")
        updateConstraintsIfNeeded() // could be useful..
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setup()
    }

}
```

(So, you'd add a UIView in storyboard, perhaps set it anchored on the left to the superview, and then change the class to TwentyPercentExample.)

Strangely this doesn't work. if you do this:

```
multiplier: 1,
constant:100
```

it nicely sets it, in realtime, in storyboard to 100 width.  Change to

```
multiplier: 1,
constant:200
```

and it works fine, changes it in realtime to 200 width. However this just doesn't seem to work:

```
multiplier: 0.2,
constant:0
```

Do I have `toItem:` wrong, or something? What's the deal?

Comment: Whenever you give constraints programmatically, you have to activate the constraints. And you didn't do that. Check this apple document https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html.

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy That’s not true. Setting `isActive` is the new and better way to do it, but either way should work. There’s a note in the docs "The isActive property automatically adds and removes the constraint from the correct view"

Comment: This is an outdated use of auto layout. Replace the entire method with this single line: `self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.2).isActive = true`. This one also would have errored since you don’t have Superview set.

Comment: @Adam, you're right - the issue is that you seemingly can't access superview in an `@IBDesignable`. Surely there's a way??

Comment: Ah, of course - you have to do it in `layoutSubviews`.   Cool

Comment: Also @AdamKaplan indeed well done for pointing out the modern usage. Quite right, thanks.

Comment: Happy to help:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you're doing this in `init` when `self.superview` is `nil`.  You should wait to add the constraint until after its been added to the superview.  Perhaps in `didMoveToSuperview()`, though this could get messy since you'll need to account for the fact that it could be added to a superview more than once.

Probably the reason the fixed constant case works is because its legal to have a constraint that's hardcoded to 100 with a `nil` item as the `toItem:` argument.

---

So, either of these

```
override func didMoveToSuperview() { setup() }
... or ...
override func layoutSubviews() { setup() }

func setup() {
    self.widthAnchor
      .constraint(equalTo: superview!.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.2)
      .isActive = true
}
```

seem to work: but seems to work irregularly and generate "agent crashed" errors in Xcode.

Comment: You're completely right Jon - in an IBDesignable, superview is not yet set at that stage.

Comment: Ahh - `layoutSubviews` is the solution.

Comment: It's true that `didMoveToSuperview()` also works.  I do not know which is preferable.  Jon, it seems to "magic" the "added more than once" problem (which is disturbing).

Comment: It does seem to add an "agent crashed" error, although everything works and it doesn't do that if you open Xcode fresh: perhaps just an Xcode bug.